# adf v2 copy data tool with 787 tables (sql server) only creates pipeline with 340 in pipeline parameters json. why?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using the Azure Data factor's Copy Data Tool.  My source is on prem sql server.  My sink target is azure sql mi.  I am selecting 787 tables and the entire wizard process works fine and seemingly generates the artifacts (pipelines, datasets, linked services, etc.).

When I ran the pipeline it only copied 340 tables due to the pipeline parameter only having the json code for 340 tables instead of 787!  I repeated the same Copy Data Tool steps and got the same results a second time.  The pipeline parameter is of type 'array' and appears to be json that was generated to feed all the tables I selected during the adf copy data tool wizard.

Am I hitting some sort of limit and do you know a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a query to get all the table names and then pass these table names to a copy activity.

```sql
select  concat(s.name,'.',ov.name) as tableName
    from 
        sysobjects o  
        join sys.objects ov on o.id = ov.object_id
        join sys.schemas s ON ov.schema_id = s.schema_id
    where o.xtype = 'U'
```

For example:

1. Use a Lookup activity to get the list of table names.
   [image]
2. Then foreach the list via exression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`.
   [image]
3. Inside the Foreach activity, we can use a Copy activity.
   [image]
4. We can edit the table name at Source tab, key in a dynamic content `@item().name`.
   [image]
5. The same we can edit table name at Sink tab.
   [image]